# Using iOS SDK in Flash CS5

Tags: ios, flash, sdk

I want to write an iOS app in Flash. Can I use iOS SDK features? I mean, for example, I want to have some list of elements in my app (like the one in the music app). Will I have to write all the classes by myself, or maybe I could use the SDK?

Not sure if I'm making it clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are making it clear. But this is not possible. If you want to use ObjectiveC/iOS library components then create a pure iPhone app using xCode on the mac.

Anyway, you may find similar flex/flash controls that may replicate the look and feel of the iOS control. Google is the limit.. ;) Good luck!